# <button> JQuery onclick works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I have a button onclick event that works fine like here:

```js
// create function to remove "popup-open" classes
// function used in onclick attribute
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.popupClose = function() {
     $( "body" ).removeClass( "popup-open" )
     $( ".overlay_btn" ).removeClass("popup-open");
      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );

// if a <button> exists
// onclick read button ID value
// add "popup-open" class to span with IDvalue as class, with fadein effect

if ( $( "button.popup" ).length )
{
  $("button.popup").click( function()
    { 
    var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
    $( "body" ).hide().addClass( "popup-open" ).fadeIn(100);
    $( "."+ btnId ).hide().addClass( "popup-open" ).fadeIn(200);
    }
 );
}

if ( $( "button.link" ).length )
{
  $("button.link").click( function()
    { 
    var btnFormAction = $(this).attr('formaction');
    var btnTarget = $(this).attr('formtarget');
    //alert(btnFormAction);
    window.open(btnFormAction, btnTarget);
    }

 );
}
```

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  margin: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #888888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
}

body:after {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    position: fixed; /* could also be absolute */ 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.overlay_btn {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11; /* 1px higher than the overlay layer */
}

body.popup-open:after, .popup-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <!--create a button with unique ID* -->
    <button id="btn-popup01" class="popup">popup button 1</button>
    <!-- create a span with the button#IDvalue as class value-->
    <span class="overlay_btn btn-popup01"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).popupClose();">close</a>
    <h3>your content title 1</h3>
      <p>your content 1</p>
    </span>
    
    <!--create a button with unique ID* -->
    <button id="btn-popup02" class="popup">popup button 2</button>
    <!-- create a span with the button#IDvalue as class value-->
    <span class="overlay_btn btn-popup02"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).popupClose();">close</a>
    <h3>your content title 2</h3>
      <p>your content 2</p>
    </span>
    
    <!--create a button with unique ID* -->
    <button id="btn-link01" class="link" formaction="http://s.emp.re/1KAZEXZ" formtarget="_blank">link button 3</button>
    
    
    <p>Here, you have a JS-less equivalent, but with much more CSS (LESS): <a href="http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg" target="_blank">http://codepen.io/maccadb7/pen/nbHEg</a></p>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the same code in this project: http://kine.sarabernaert.be/contact/

> Button 'Maak Afspraak' gives a popup
>   on the popup there's a button 'Ga naar aanmelden' that links to a outside link.
>
> > I can't get working this link. When click, nothing happens. In my demo setup, same code is working well.

Any hints? Don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thx!

Comment: but `Ga naar aanmelden` isn't a `<a>` to navigate to another link

Comment: are you using some type of plugin or library? otherwise like Dhiraj said, you are not using an anchor tag. Buttons will not take you to any links, you need to use `a` tags instead

Comment: Javascript is doing the thing to do something onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `.click()` method to `.on()` method and place them inside `$(document).ready` at the bottom of the page

In your case, instead of `if ( $( "button.link" ).length )` you can use something like below.

```
$("body").on('click', 'button.link', function(){ 
    var btnFormAction = $(this).attr('formaction');
    var btnTarget = $(this).attr('formtarget');
    window.open(btnFormAction, btnTarget);        
});
```

Overall, your scripts should probably look like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", "button.popup", function(){ 
      var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
      $( "body" ).hide().addClass( "popup-open" ).fadeIn(100);
      $( "."+ btnId ).hide().addClass( "popup-open" ).fadeIn(200);
    }).on('click', 'button.link', function(){ 
      var btnFormAction = $(this).attr('formaction');
      var btnTarget = $(this).attr('formtarget');
      window.open(btnFormAction, btnTarget);        
    });

    $.fn.popupClose = function() {
      $( "body" ).removeClass( "popup-open" )
      $( ".overlay_btn" ).removeClass("popup-open");
      return this;
    };
});
```

I tested it on your site and it seems to be working after that. I got redirected to a login page I guess.

Hope this helps.