# Buttons Not Working When Adding Table Rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

I have a table with a column that has 2 buttons, edit and deactivate. Both function perfectly. However, I also have a button outside of the table that adds a row to the table. On all added rows, neither my edit nor deactivate button work at all. How do I fix this?

HTML/PHP:

```
<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><button class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="deactivate" name="deactivate">Deactivate</button></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Deactivate Row -----

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.deactivate').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
      $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
      $this.text(function(i, t) {
        return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
      });
    }
  })
});

// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    var element8 = document.createElement("input");
    element7.type = "button";
    element8.type = "button";
    element7.name="edit";
    element8.name="deactivate";
    element7.value="Edit";
    element8.value="Deactivate";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);
    cell7.appendChild(element8);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
        $this.html('Save');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        var isValid = true;
        var errors = '';
        $('#myDialogBox').empty();
        tds.each(function(){
             var type = $(this).attr('class');
             var value = $(this).text();
             switch(type){
                 case "buyer_id":
                     if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                         isValid = false;
                         errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                      }
                     break;
                case "poc_n":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_e":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_p":
                    if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";    
                    }
                    break;
             }
        })
        if(isValid){
            $this.html('Edit');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
        }else{
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086585/button-jquery-onclick-works-only-once

Comment: Is the first row working or not even this one ? If the first row work, check my answer ;)

Comment: Yes, everything works except for additional added rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamically added buttons are not binded to anything.

The solution is to make your onload bindings a function that you can call anytime...

```
function bindDeactivate() {
  $('.deactivate').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
      $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
      $this.text(function(i, t) {
        return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Bind the button on load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the deactivate button click to the function
    bindDeactivate();
});
```

At the end of your add row function, bind the button.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    // Skipped a couple lines...

    cell7.appendChild(element7);
    cell7.appendChild(element8);

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    bindDeactivate();
}
```

You will be able to do the same for the edit button...
;)

**EDIT**

You had another problem.
Your dynamically added button do NOT have the associated classes.

Add this to your `function addRow(tableID)` to add a class to the Deactivate button.

```
var setClass = document.createAttribute("class");
setClass.value = "deactivate";
element8.setAttributeNode(setClass);
```

Do the same for the edit button.

See my **[CodePen here](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GjOYrZ?editors=1010)**.

**EDIT**

Okay... Another issue you had:
In your initial HTML, the buttons are `<button>` tags.
While the dynamically added ones are `<input type="button">`

This causes `$this.text(function(i, t) {` to be not working on the `<input type="button">`.

I changed them for `<input type="button">` in your HTML.
And changed `$this.text(function(i, t) {` for `$this.val(function(i, t) {`

I also improved the "double click effect" by unbinding before re-bind... At the end of the `addRow(tableID)` function.

```
// Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
$('#html_master').off("click",'.deactivate');
bindDeactivate();
```

Please, re-check my codePen again
It is now working (only for Deactivate/Activate button)
You can apply the same logic for the Edit button...
;)

Comment: So the code to bind the button on load...where exactly does that go? And for adding the code at the end of the add row function....i put this inside the function but at the very end correct?

Comment: Correct for «inside the function but at the very end». For the onload... It is inside a document ready... so anywhere is good.

Comment: If it still does'nt work... (I suddenly have a small doubt) try `$(document).find('.deactivate').click(function() {`

Comment: Hold on... Will try it on my side.

Comment: Okay so...when i add a row and click the button it works! However, running in to a couple extra problems now...when i click the button, the text stays as deactivate even after clicking it when it should say Activate...also...when clicking an original row, it asks me if i want to deactivate the row, then back-to-back, asks me if i want to activate it...

Comment: I see... Hold on again ;)

Comment: I made a couple changes to my CodePen... This is explained in my edited answer.

Comment: It definitely looks like it works in your code, but i copied it to my code and it looks like im still having the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124920/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-rataiczak24).

Comment: if you get this notification and have time, could you come back to the chat? I have some questions about the binding of the edit button

Answer (score 0):

bocz you bind event on load so it work for existing data row but newly added row dont have any binding, try below code to bind event.

```
$(document).on('click','.deactivate',function() {
var $this = $(this);
var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
  $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
  $this.text(function(i, t) {
    return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
  });
}
});
```

and for edit

```
$(document).on('click','.edit',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
});
});
```

Comment: I put both sets of code into my script and it doesn't seem to work. The add row function won't even work now.

Comment: check the closing brackets. as i just copy past your code.
i missed closing bracke in edit code.

Answer (score 0):

use code

```
 $(document).on('click','.deactivate',function() {
var $this = $(this);
var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
  $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
  $this.text(function(i, t) {
    return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
  });
}
});

$(document).on('click','.edit',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
});
if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
    $this.html('Save');
    tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
} else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    tds.each(function(){
         var type = $(this).attr('class');
         var value = $(this).text();
         switch(type){
             case "buyer_id":
                 if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                     isValid = false;
                     errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                  }
                 break;
            case "poc_n":
                if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    isValid = false;
                    errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                }
                break;
            case "poc_e":
                if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    isValid = false;
                    errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                }
                break;
            case "poc_p":
                if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    isValid = false;
                    errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";    
                }
                break;
         }
    })
    if(isValid){
        $this.html('Edit');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    }else{
        alert(errors);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Add this this two line
element7.setAttribute("class","edit");
element8.setAttribute("class","deactivate");   bcoz in yr code you not add class to new button. i test an its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

> The Main reason why the newly added Rows do not respond to the `edit` and `deactivate` Methods is because they were dynamically created and thus were not bound to those initially declared `onclick` Events as the others. You may have to simply attach those events after creating the rows. The code snippet below attempts to illustrate how.
>  **Note:** 
> *The snippet below combines all your Javascript code under the JQuery `ready` Method since there would be no need to have separate `ready` Methods in one Script. Secondly, to create the new Row, Jquery (rather than Raw Javascript was used). Just for simplicity.*

**HTML**

```
<table id="html_master">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Vendor</td>
        <td>Buyer ID</td>
        <td>POC Name</td>
        <td>POC Email</td>
        <td>POC Phone</td>
        <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
                <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
                <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
                <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>
                <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
                <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
                <td><button class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
                    <button class="deactivate" name="deactivate">Deactivate</button></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="add-button-wrapper">
    <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" id="rowAdder">
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT: JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var rowAdder    = $("#rowAdder");
        var editButton  = $(".edit");
        var deActivator = $('.deactivate');

        /* EVENT BINDINGS & HANDLING*/

        // BIND THE CLICK ACTION TO DEACTIVATION HANDLER
        deActivator.click(deactivate);

        // BIND THE CLICK EVENT TO THE EDITING HANDLER:
        editButton.click(handleEdit);

        // BIND THE CLICK ACTION TO THE NEW-ROW PROCESSING HANDLER:
        rowAdder.click(addRow);


        /* CALL-BACK FUNCTIONS:*/

        // HANDLE THE EDITING
        function handleEdit(evt) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
                return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
            });
            if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
                $this.html('Save');
                tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
            } else {
                var isValid = true;
                var errors = '';
                $('#myDialogBox').empty();
                tds.each(function(){
                    var type = $(this).attr('class');
                    var value = $(this).text();
                    switch(type){
                        case "buyer_id":
                            if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                                isValid = false;
                                errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                            }
                            break;
                        case "poc_n":
                            if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                isValid = false;
                                errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                            }
                            break;
                        case "poc_e":
                            if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                isValid = false;
                                errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                            }
                            break;
                        case "poc_p":
                            if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                isValid = false;
                                errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                })
                if(isValid){
                    $this.html('Edit');
                    tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
                }else{
                    alert(errors);
                }
            }
        }

        // HANDLE DEACTIVATION
        function deactivate(evt) {
            var $this   = $(this);
            var $tr     = $this.closest('tr');
            var action  = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
                $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
                $this.text(function(i, t) {
                    return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
                });
            }
        }

        // ADD NEW ROW
        function addRow(evt) {
            var table       = $("#html_master");
            var rows        = table.children("tr");
            var rowCount    = rows.length;
            var row         = table.insertRow(rowCount);


            // SIMPLY CREATE A NEW ROW OBJECT AND APPEND IT TO THE rows VARIABLE.
            var newRow      = "<tr>";
            newRow         += "<td class='mr_id' contenteditable='false'>" + rowCount + "</td>";
            newRow         += "<td class='buyer_id' contenteditable='false'><input type='text' name='txtbox[]' />" + "</td>";
            newRow         += "<td class='poc_n' contenteditable='false'><input type='text' name='txtbox[]' />" + "</td>";
            newRow         += "<td class='poc_e' contenteditable='false'><input type='text' name='txtbox[]' />" + "</td>";
            newRow         += "<td class='poc_p' contenteditable='false'><input type='text' name='txtbox[]' />" + "</td>";
            newRow         += "<td class='mr_id' contenteditable='false'><input type='text' name='txtbox[]' />" + "</td>";
            newRow         += "<td class='mr_id' contenteditable='false'>";
            newRow         += "<button class='edit' name='edit'>Edit</button>";
            newRow         += "<button class='deactivate' name='deactivate'>Deactivate</button>";
            newRow         += "</td>";
            newRow         += "</tr>";

            // APPEND THE NEW ROW...
            table.append(newRow);

            // RE-BIND THE EVENTS ON THE BUTTONS SINCE THESE WERE DYNAMICALLY CREATED

            // BIND THE CLICK ACTION TO DEACTIVATION HANDLER
            table.find("deactivate").click(deactivate);

            // BIND THE CLICK EVENT TO THE EDITING HANDLER:
            table.find("edit").click(handleEdit);
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use an **id** instead of the **class** like :

```
<td><button class="edit" id="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="deactivate" id="deactivate" name="deactivate">Deactivate</button></td>
```

And in the jQuery, replace the ".edit" by "#edit" and ".deactivate" by "#deactivate".

Comment: this does not work...ID is specific to one element....i have multiple rows so I am pretty sure that CLASS must be used here

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the onclick on the html button and use it to call a function in jQuery? Just a guess

Comment: on one page all emement must have unique id.  then only jquery understood the selection of eleent else it will select always one (first) ID element.